# Calling a Python function in C++ with Swig

Tags: python, swig

Here is my c++ code:

```
void callMethod(void (*someMethod)()) {
    (*someMethod)();
}
```

My Swig .i file is:

```
%module test
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT

extern void callMethod(void (*someMethod)());
%}

%typemap (in) void*
%{
    $1 = PyCObject_AsVoidPtr($input);
%}


extern void callMethod(void (*someMethod)());
```

Here is my error:

```
In [1]: import test

In [2]: b=test.callMethod

In [3]: def func():
   ...:     print "hi"
   ...:     
   ...:     

In [4]: b(func)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

$DIR/<ipython console> in <module>()

TypeError: in method 'callMethod', argument 1 of type 'void (*)()'
```

How can I do what I want with Swig?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pointers to functions and callbacks](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn30)